# Reply in specific language

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to make the replies returned from `google.maps.Geocoder().geocoder` to be in a specific language?

I can't see it in [the docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding).

EDIT: Just to be clear, I do understand that the replies can be forced to a specific language when loading the google maps script itself, but what I'm asking is if it's possible to change the language at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the [Geocoding Web Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro)

That has an [optional `language` parameter](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#language-param):

> language — The language in which to return results. See the list of supported domain languages. Note that we often update supported languages so this list may not be exhaustive. If language is not supplied, the geocoder will attempt to use the native language of the domain from which the request is sent wherever possible.